# What's the shortcut to open last closed tab in Xcode

Tags: xcode

Always talking about Xcode.

Open new tab is `command + T`
Close current tab is `command + W`

Is there any shortcut to open last closed tab in Xcode (like in any web browser)?

Comment: Do you have any news?

Comment: Nothing yet.. Maybe not possible for now?

Comment: Still can't do this in Xcode 14.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you close it, press

```
Command + Control + < (back arrow)
```

It will re open the closed tab in XCode

Comment: Doesn't work for me. What is the name of this in the `Key Bindings` Preferences tab?

Comment: Go Back (Navigate menu). Filter by "back, it's the first one.